# Sorting multiple array objects with different keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, ecmascript-6

Before, I was combining 2 arrays into one array and using `sort()`, I was able to sort them by `created_at`.

```
let result = [...item.messages, ...item.chat_messages]
result.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.created_at) - new Date(a.created_at))
item.messages = result
```

Now, I am in another scenario. I want to add one more array (sms_messages) into this array and however want it to order by its `scheduled_at` field.

Is it possible to achieve it with this approach?

```
let result = [...item.messages, ...item.chat_messages, ...item.sms_messages]
// and order by messages' and chat_messages' created_at (like above) together as 
// sms_messages' sheduled_at
```

Comment: Does only sms has the `scheduled_at` prop?

Comment: @OriDrori, yes. Others should use `created_at` like before but sms needs to use `scheduled_at`. So I can give a list in related order

Comment: Please provide an actual complete example of the data structure you want to work with. It's hard to discern from your description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `||` to get the first of both properties it finds to be there, assuming that each object has at least one of both properties, but `scheduled_at` gets precedence:

```
result.sort((a, b) => 
    new Date(b.scheduled_at || b.created_at) - new Date(a.scheduled_at || a.created_at))
```

Comment: That seems like a good approach, however sms has `created_at` property as well as `scheduled_at` and I think it is ordering by `created_at` rather than scheduled at

Comment: That should not be the case: `scheduled_at` is taken if it exists before falling back to `created_at`. If an object has both properties, `scheduled_at` will be used.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry. It is working like charm! Thanks a million

Answer (score 0):

Just check which which property exists and use it to sort the objects.

```
const sortByDate = props => {
  return (a, b) => {
    let propA = props.find(p => a.hasOwnProperty(p));
    let propB = props.find(p => b.hasOwnProperty(p));
    if(!propA || !propB) return 0;
    return new Date(b[propB]) - new Date(a[propA]);
  };
}

result.sort(sortByDate(['scheduled_at', 'created_at']));
```

Comment: But sms_messages has both properties `scheduled_at` and `created_at`. I think this won't solve this because of it

Comment: In my example it prioritises the `scheduled_at` attribute and then falls back to `created_at`. So if `scheduled_at` is present on the object it will get sorted by `sheduled_at`.